# valid model c# properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, annotations, asp.net-web-api2

somebody know, how to not allow other properties in controllers using annotations or some other method?

for example, I have a model

```
[required]
public string user_name {get;set;}

[required]
public string password {get;set;}
```

Then in the request I send this body:

```
{
"user_name" : "user",
"password" : "12345",
"other_property" : "here is the problem"
}
```

The problem is that the validation passed, I need for example send in response something like "property not allowed"

Comment: Why does it matter whether other properties are passed up? Why do you want it to fail validation?

Comment: I need indicate to user that this property or other properties not working or not allowed in the controller, in this case is because the api is public and I need indicate that it can and can't do the api

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple extension method validating against a generic type using JSON.NET:

```
static class ValidationExtensions
{
    public static void ValidateNoUnknownProperties<TValid>(this string json)
    {
        var validPropertyNames = typeof(TValid).GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
        var deserializedJson = JObject.Parse(json);
        var invalidPropertyNames = deserializedJson.Properties()
                                       .Where(p => !validPropertyNames.Contains(p.Name))
                                       .Select(p => p.Name)
                                       .ToList();

        if (invalidPropertyNames.Count() > 0)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Invalid Properties: {string.Join(",", invalidPropertyNames)}");
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
class Dto
{
    public string user_name { get; set; }

    public string password { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var json = @"
        {
            ""user_name"" : ""user"",
            ""password"" : ""12345"",
            ""other_property"" : ""here is the problem"",
            ""something_else"" : ""yeah...""
        }";

        json.ValidateNoUnknownProperties<Dto>();
    }
}
```

And the output:

```
Invalid Properties: other_property,something_else"
```

**Edit**: Depending of your usage of the JSON, there might of course be better ways to do this. And the above code should be checked for some obvious possible error cases of course, but it could be a first shot.

Comment: The solution is very cool, but it have a problem with deep json and exist conflict with the annotations, because for example some properties are optional and this solution is very very strong with properties, but is a good begining, Thank so much!

Answer (score 0):

Very good library to make Validation is [FluentValidation](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it, I remember me to Joi for nodejs https://github.com/hapijs/joi